# Animate view's width to match parent?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create the following concept:

First expand the view to its parent's width (it's not the same).
Then expand the view to its parent's height.

I know I can create the sequence with `AnimatorSet()`. What I cannot find is what property/-ies to animate to create the result.

My thoughts for the width animation:
I would probably need to animate either two points which define left and right or alternatively animate the translation and the width.

I'm a bit confused, which properties would do the trick?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that there is no need to complicate things, you can use width property first then followed by height in AnimatorSet, Your view gravity property will define in which direction view will expand ...

Comment: Can you give some details about gravity: what happens if I have e.g. a gridview which doesn't use gravity (afaik)?

Comment: What I meant was that the view's gravity w.r.t it's parent will determine the direction in which view will expand, so suppose you GridView was inside LinearLayout(with gravity say right), then on increasing GridView size it will starts appearing on the screen from right, and similarly you can figure out ....

Comment: @Diolor How does this actually answer your question? You said you could not find the properties to animate, and this answer does not specify them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define custom properties to do this (I know, silly). Height example:

```
public static final Property<View, Integer> PROPERTY_HEIGHT =
        new Property<View, Integer>(Integer.class, "viewLayoutHeight") {

            @Override
            public void set(View object, Integer value) {
                object.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                object.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer get(View object) {
                return object.getLayoutParams().height;
            }
        };
```

Then use as a normal property:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, PROPERTY_HEIGHT, minHeight, maxHeight);
```

You'll need to get the parent dimensions at runtime (perhaps using a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`).

Comment: Haven't tried but just asking what about the direction of the expansion?

Comment: That wasn't a part of your question. Please accept this answer if it satisfied your original question. You could have to control the translation separately.